App shortcut actions not showing on iOS 18 shortcuts app
First, apology if my English is not quite good.
We have developed an iOS app in objective-C and added integrations for shortcuts app - more specific the "automation" part of the app.
Basically, user opens shortcuts app, select automation and when scanning NFC tag, user can select an action and our app shows 3 different actions. User select action, opens the app and action is executed. That all done in Obj-C and was working very well with no complaints till users start to update to iOS18. 
Now, when user starts to add automation, only thing they can do is select "open app". Our app actions are not showing any more. Is there something new in iOS 18 we have to update our app.
I know Obje-C is considered "old", but the cost of upgrading an existing app and time is not available at the moment.
Here's a code snippet of out shortcutIntent:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>group.lw.grp1</string>
        <string>group.lw.grp2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>

Info-plist
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IntentsRestrictedWhileLocked</key>
            <array/>
            <key>IntentsRestrictedWhileProtectedDataUnavailable</key>
            <array/>
            <key>IntentsSupported</key>
            <array>
                <string>LockIntent</string>
                <string>TrunkIntent</string>
                <string>UnlockIntent</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.intents-service</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>IntentHandler</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>

IntentHandler
@implementation IntentHandler

-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    self.started = false;
    self.handler = [[AppIntentHandler alloc] init];
    self.handler.userInfo = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    return self;
}
- (id)handlerForIntent:(INIntent *)intent {
    // This is the default implementation.  If you want different objects to handle different intents,
    // you can override this and return the handler you want for that particular intent.
                   
    
    if(!self.started){
        self.started = YES;
        if([intent isKindOfClass:[LockIntent class]]){
            NSLog(@"*intent lock selected*");
            self.handler.userInfo = [self assignUserInfo:@"lock"];
        }else if([intent isKindOfClass:[UnlockIntent class]]){
            NSLog(@"*intent unlock selected*");
            self.handler.userInfo = [self assignUserInfo:@"unlock"];
        }else if([intent isKindOfClass:[TrunkIntent class]]){
            NSLog(@"*intent trunk selected*");
            self.handler.userInfo = [self assignUserInfo:@"trunk"];
        }
    }else{
        self.started = NO;
    }
    
    
    return self.handler;
}

A custom class to handle each intent
@interface AppIntentHandler : NSObject<LockIntentHandling, UnlockIntentHandling, TrunkIntentHandling>
@implementation AppIntentHandler

#pragma mark - response handlers
- (void)handleLock:(nonnull LockIntent *)intent completion:(nonnull void (^)(LockIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
    LockIntentResponse *response = [[LockIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:LockIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:[self lockUserActivity]];
    completion(response);
}

- (void)handleUnlock:(nonnull UnlockIntent *)intent completion:(nonnull void (^)(UnlockIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
    UnlockIntentResponse *response = [[UnlockIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:UnlockIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:[self unlockUserActivity]];
    completion(response);
}

- (void)handleTrunk:(nonnull TrunkIntent *)intent completion:(nonnull void (^)(TrunkIntentResponse * _Nonnull))completion {
    TrunkIntentResponse *response = [[TrunkIntentResponse alloc] initWithCode:TrunkIntentResponseCodeContinueInApp userActivity:[self trunkUserActivity]];
    completion(response);
}

What needs to be done to make our app's actions show in shortcuts app again.
Thanks in advance
